# Trying to switch stages after a splash screen in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, fxmlloader

I'm trying to display a splash screen until I load all necessary resources and open the main stage afterwards, but I keep running into `InvocationTargetException`.

In other words, my primary stage loads a FXML which has a Controller which looks like this:

```
public class SplashController {

    @FXML
    VBox splashScreenVBox = new VBox();

    @FXML
    protected void initialize() throws InterruptedException, IOException {

        Stage primaryStage = (Stage) splashScreenVBox.getScene().getWindow();
        primaryStage.close();
        new MainStage();            
    }
}
```

The `MainStage` class is just loading a FXML and showing the scene:

```
public MainStage() throws IOException {

    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/core/views/Main.fxml"));
    this.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 600));
    this.show();
}
```

The error that I'm getting points towards a line on which I `FXMLLoader.load()` the FXML the first time (I have two FXML files, one for each stage).

Can someone shed some light on why this happens and preferably how to correctly work with the `FXMLLoader`, in case that what I'm doing is an issue, please?

**Edit: Stacktrace**

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/REDACTED/out/production/REDACTED/core/views/Splash.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2571)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at core.Scenes.start(Scenes.java:19)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2566)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at core.controllers.SplashController.initialize(SplashController.java:18)
    ... 28 more
Exception running application core.Scenes
```

Comment: Post the entire stack trace of the `InvocationTargetException`.

Comment: Also, don't initialize `FXML` annotated fields: `VBox splashScreenVBox = new VBox()`. That instance you created is just going to be replaced by the one injected by the `FXMLLoader`.

Comment: @Slaw thanks, I've corrected the `@FXML` annotated field and edited in the stacktrace.

Comment: I should add that the scenes/stages are running concurrently for a while, until the first one gets closed, but that's visible from the code. Isn't that an issue for FXMLLoader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the stack trace you are getting a `NullPointerException` in the `initialize` method of your `SplashController` on line `18`. I'm going to assume that line `18` is this line:

```
Stage primaryStage = (Stage) splashScreenVBox.getScene().getWindow();
```

The issue is most likely this call: `getScene().getWindow()`. The method `getScene()` will return `null` here because `splashScreenVBox` is not part of a `Scene` yet. How could it be? The `initialize` method is called *during* the execution of `FXMLLoader.load()`. This means you have not had the chance to add the result of `FXMLLoader.load()` to a `Scene` yet.

To fix this one option is adding a method to your `SplashController` that does the loading for `MainStage`.

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("your/resource"));
Parent root = loader.load();

Stage splashStage = new Stage();
splashStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
splashStage.show();

SplashController controller = loader.getController();
controller.loadMainApp(splashStage);
```

I passed the `splashStage` to the method so you can hide/close it when ready to show the main `Stage`. Depending on the design of your code there may be other ways to do this than passing an argument.

---

An example of how to create an abstract controller that will automatically call a method when the root is added to a `Scene` and that `Scene` has been added to a `Window`.

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Window;

public abstract class AbstractController<T extends Node> {

  // protected so subclasses can access the root
  // directly. You could also hide this behind a
  // getter.
  @FXML protected T root;

  // Subclasses that override this method must call the
  // super implementation
  @FXML
  protected void initialize() {
    Consumer<Window> onNewWindow = this::onAddedToWindow;
    Consumer<Scene> onNewScene = scene ->
        scene.windowProperty().addListener(new SelfRemovingChangeListener<>(onNewWindow));
    root.sceneProperty().addListener(new SelfRemovingChangeListener<>(onNewScene));
  }

  protected abstract void onAddedToWindow(Window window);

  private static class SelfRemovingChangeListener<T> implements ChangeListener<T> {

    private final Consumer<? super T> onNewValue;

    private SelfRemovingChangeListener(Consumer<? super T> onNewValue) {
      this.onNewValue = onNewValue;
    }

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends T> observable, T oldValue, T newValue) {
      onNewValue.accept(newValue);
      observable.removeListener(this);
    }

  }

}
```

This requires that you have a `fx:id="root"` in your FXML file and that the root object is a `Node`. The `onAddedToWindow` is only called the *first* time the `root` has been added to a `Window`. You still have to add the `root` to a `Window` elsewhere (wherever you call `FXMLLoader.load`).

Comment: Oh it makes sense to me finally. It was just as you said, I tried to get the scene from an object which wasn't there yet, `during initialize()`. Thanks very much for clearing this up. I've edited the code and it works precisely as intended now. Is there any method I could call instead of `initialize()` that works in a "after load" manner that gets invoked automatically, please?

Comment: @Dropout Technically the `initialize` method _is_ the "after load" method. You want a method that's called automatically after the root is added a `Scene` _and_ that `Scene` is added to a `Stage`, right? The issue is that happens _outside_ of the `FXMLLoader`'s control. It has no idea _when_ this will happen. The closest you can get is by creating an abstract controller that will add this behavior. I'll edit my answer with an example.

Comment: Thank you, it's really helpful!

Comment: @Dropout example added

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated!